# PowerShell - Select specific line from string

Tags: string, powershell

I'm trying to find a way to grab a specific line from a string based on line number.

For instance, I want to pull whatever is in line 19.

From what I understand, I could do this with `Get-Content` and `-Index` if I was pulling from a file. Is there an alternative when working with variables instead of files?

Comment: Does the variable contain just one big multi-line string, or multiple strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a single, multi-line string `$str` as the input, and `$lineNo` as the `1`-based line number to extract:

```
($str -split '\r?\n')[$lineNo - 1]
```

- `-split '\r?\n'` splits the input string into an *array* of lines.

  - Note: Regex `\r?\n` is designed to match both Windows-style CRLF newlines and Unix-style LF-only newlines.
    If your multi-line string *literal* were to be defined in your source code, for instance, the newline style of the source code's *file* determines the string's.
- Then `[$lineNo - 1]` accesses the line of interest; given that line numbers are `1`-based but array indices are `0`-based, `- 1` must be applied to the line number.

---

Example:

```
$str = @'
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
'@

$lineNo = 3

($str -split '\r?\n')[$lineNo - 1]  # -> 'line 3'
```

Comment: @drummerof13: Glad to hear it was helpful; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how your string/variable is constructed and what delimiters your data has.

Maybe these examples inspire you...

```
$var1 = @(
'one'
'two'
'three'
)

$var2 = "four,five,six"

$var3 = @'
seven
eight
nine
'@

# array
$var1[1]

# string with delimeter
$var2.Split(',')[1]

# here string like raw file with CRLF as delim
$var3.Split("`r`n")[1]
```